# Set default renderer

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I know how to change the default renderer using **Matlab GUI**, but I would like to use painters renderer instead of opengl all the time instead of changing it every time.

Is there a way to set default renderer in Matlab by using set command. I'm looking for command like: `set(groot, 'defaultRenderer', 'painters')`

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see [**here**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/default-property-values.html) you can build every "default property" you wish by concatenating `default + class name + property`.

In your case it would be:

```
set(0, 'defaultFigureRenderer', 'painters')
```

respectively

```
set(groot, 'defaultFigureRenderer', 'painters')
```

---

You can check by `get(groot,'default')`.

Be aware that the default is just set for the current session! Restarting would omit the changes. To set it permanently put the line into a [**start-up file**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html)
.